# Error code 58 on my Kawasaki Vulcan 1700 e9f 2009

Tags: motorcycle, cel, kawasaki, vulcan

Wot is error code 58 and how to fix it,  my bike has been running great for around 17000 mils but now when I start it it runs fine but won't rev it's like limp mode,my bike has aftermarket exhaust system and the clean air system off and by passed and a small breather filter fitted, o2 sensor removed and by passed,  it also has a Large K&N filter fitted, any help please

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You state the "CO2 sensor removed and by passed" ... do you mean an O2 sensor? This is electronic fuel injection, correct? If both are correct, you can't bypass the O2 sensor and expect it to run correctly. I don't know if that's your issue, but it is an issue.

Comment: Sorry yes , sausages fingers gettin in the way again 

Comment: Forgot to add I have a fuel management system  fitted, the error code 58 ,I don't know if it's been the problem but I found a small connection on the alarm system (data tool imobilzer) the fault code is gone and she runs normally